# cannot install new software on my pi

Tags: software-installation

whenever i try and install anything i get

```
Reading package lists... 0%
```

then about a second later

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ts... 0%
```

it appears to print `**pi@raspberrypi ~ $**` over  `**Reading package lists... 0%**`

to get

```
 ***pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ts... 0%***
```

when i did `df -h` i get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          3.6G  2.9G  591M  83% /
/dev/root       3.6G  2.9G  591M  83% /
devtmpfs        180M     0  180M   0% /dev
tmpfs            38M  232K   38M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            75M     0   75M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   56M   19M   38M  34% /boot
```

Iv'e  done `sudo rpi-update` and `fsck` too, but no success.

Why cannt i install new software.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does running 'apt-cache clean' yield a new error?

Answer (score 1):

I tried `apt-get autoclean`, but that made no difference, then i tried `apt-get clean` which did the job!

Thanks Rune Vikestad for suggesting this, I can now install packages again. Does this suggest i had too much installed on my 4GB sd card or something else?